# @SerializedName val can not be initialized in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

Here I have a POST request using Retrofit2 returns a json String that has a field named "messageCode"

and there is a BaseResponse class that defines a "val code"  with @SerializedName("code") and it's read only.

```
open class BaseResponse(@SerializedName(value = "mc", alternate = ["code"]) val code: Int)
```

So I write a class extends BaseResponse and take that "messageCode" then give it to the "code" in super like this:

```
class MyConcreteResponse( 
    messageCode: Int?, 
    val data: List<String>?
) :BaseResponse(code = messageCode)
```

but it turns out that when I access the "code", it is just 0, not equal to the "messageCode"

I need "code" to be loaded because another READ-ONLY class access it, so how to take that "messageCode" and give it to the "code" in super?

Comment: did you checked is "messageCode" has the value when you got the response

Comment: yes, when I add "val" before "messageCode" in MyConcreteResponse, I can access it and print the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you are using gson library.
gson is not using constructor to initiate the data class and variable , it uses java reflection. so you have to write a custom class that implements **JsonDeserializer** and write your own deserializer to parse the value and pass it to parent class.